# Whether the CIL code generated for a delegate type is compile time or runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, delegates, cil

Lets say there is a delegate referring to two methods say Add() and Sub() . All i am asking is whether the C# compiler generates the equivalent IL code at runtime or at the compiletime ?

ex:

```
public int delegate Dele(int,int);

//methods
int Add(int a,int b)
{
    //...
}
int Sub(int a,int b)
{
    //...
}


//here comes the condition

if(cond)
{
   Del+=Add;
}
else
{
   Del+=Sub;
}

int ans=Del(4,4);
```

here whether the compiler generates the cil code for both true and false conditions at compiletime or runtime?

Comment: Why don't you look at the MSIL generated at compile-time and see?  The `ildasm` tool is good at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which method is referred is only resolved when it invoked, i.e. at the runtime. In our case, yes it contributes a little for the optimization cause it had been invoked only once and there will be always only one CIL code in the execution path. Hope this is the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There's no IL for delegates in the first place.

```
Del+=Add;
```

Is syntactic sugar for

```
Del += new Dele(Add);
```

`Dele` is the delegate type. Under the hood, this is a class with an `Invoke(int, int)` method (as well as an `BeginInvoke`/`EndInvoke` pair).

When you call:

```
int ans=Del(4,4);
```

It's syntactic sugar for:

```
int ans = Del.Invoke(4, 4);
```

The `Invoke` method has no IL code - it's declared as `virtual extern` and handled by the runtime. Of course, the actual machine code required by the call is geerated by the JIT.

---

Here's a quote from the [CLI spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf), page 172 (emphasis mine):

> Delegates shall be declared `sealed`, and the only members a delegate shall have are either the first two or all four methods as specified here. These methods shall be declared `runtime` and `managed`
>   (§II.15.4.3). **They shall not have a body, since that body shall be created automatically by the VES.**
>   Other methods available on delegates are inherited from the class `System.Delegate` in the Base Class Library (see Partition IV).

Comment: in such case , can delegates help a bit for optimization??

Comment: @Necromancer delegates are quite fast, yes, but I don't see how they relate to optimization. If you have an optimization question, you should post it as a new question here, and state your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

> here whether the compiler generates the cil code for both true and
>   false conditions at compiletime or runtime?

Both execution path CIL is generated. You can see this with a compiling code example. This:

```
public void X(int x)
{
    Dele del;
    if(Condition(x))
    {
        del = new Dele(Add);
        del(1,1);
    }
    else
    {
        del = new Dele(Sub);
        del(2,1);
    }
}

public bool Condition(int i)
{
    return i % 2 == 0;
}
```

Produces this following IL:

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void X () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x205c
    // Code size 51 (0x33)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.5
    IL_0002: call instance bool C::Condition(int32)
    IL_0007: brfalse.s IL_001e
    IL_0009: ldarg.0
    IL_000a: ldftn instance int32 C::Add(int32, int32)
    IL_0010: newobj instance void C/Dele::.ctor(object, native int)
    IL_0015: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0016: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0017: callvirt instance int32 C/Dele::Invoke(int32, int32)
    IL_001c: pop
    IL_001d: ret
    IL_001e: ldarg.0
    IL_001f: ldftn instance int32 C::Sub(int32, int32)
    IL_0025: newobj instance void C/Dele::.ctor(object, native int)
    IL_002a: ldc.i4.2
    IL_002b: ldc.i4.1
    IL_002c: callvirt instance int32 C/Dele::Invoke(int32, int32)
    IL_0031: pop
    IL_0032: ret
} // end of method C::X
```

The first code execution can be see starting `IL_000a` where `Add` is loaded. The second one can be seen at `IL_001f` where `Sub` is loaded.

The only thing that happens at runtime, is the creation of the delegate which inherits from `MulticastDelegate`, where three method are created: `Invoke`, `BeingInvoke` and `EndInvoke`, as stated in [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf):

> Delegates are created by defining a class that derives from the base
>   type System.Delegate (see Partition IV). Each delegate type shall
>   provide a method named `Invoke` with appropriate parameters, and each
>   instance of a delegate forwards calls to its `Invoke` method to one or
>   more static or instance methods on particular objects that are
>   delegate-assignable-to (§II.14.6.1) the signature of the delegate. The
>   objects and methods to which it delegates are chosen when the delegate
>   instance is created.  In addition to an instance constructor and an
>   Invoke method, delegates can optionally have two additional methods:
>   `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke`. These are used for asynchronous calls.

```
// Nested Types
.class nested public auto ansi sealed Dele
    extends [mscorlib]System.MulticastDelegate
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor (
            object 'object',
            native int 'method'
        ) runtime managed 
    {
    } // end of method Dele::.ctor

    .method public hidebysig newslot virtual 
        instance int32 Invoke (
            int32 x,
            int32 y
        ) runtime managed 
    {
    } // end of method Dele::Invoke

    .method public hidebysig newslot virtual 
        instance class [mscorlib]System.IAsyncResult BeginInvoke (
            int32 x,
            int32 y,
            class [mscorlib]System.AsyncCallback callback,
            object 'object'
        ) runtime managed 
    {
    } // end of method Dele::BeginInvoke

    .method public hidebysig newslot virtual 
        instance int32 EndInvoke (
            class [mscorlib]System.IAsyncResult result
        ) runtime managed 
    {
    } // end of method Dele::EndInvoke

} // end of class Dele
```